# unrecognized expression error when setting val() to element using id but not when fetching value

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

I have multiple panels and they can be edited with ajax. When edit is clicked it get me the id of the panel and other panel details. then it is passed to the modal and ajax function is called. There is no problem till this. The problem is when updating the edited values to the panel.

```
<div class="panel" id="{{$candidate->id}}">
   <div class="card_details">
    <b><p id = "card_phone">{{$candidate->phone}}</p></b>
    <b><small id="card_email">{{$candidate->email}}</small></b><br><br>
   </div>
</div>
```

the {{candidate->id}} is different for each panel. I able to get the data inside the panel with jquery like this

```
var panel = $('div#'+candidate_id+'.panel');
var name = panel.find('p#card_name').text();
var phone = panel.find('div.card_details p#card_phone').text();
var email = panel.find('div.card_details small#card_email').text();
```

But when i try to set the update the value on the same panel i get the error

> unrecognized expression: div#[object HTMLInputElement].panel

```
function updateCandidateDetails(data,can_id){

var candidate_id = can_id;

$.each(data,function(key,value){
    $.each(value,function(index,titleObj){

    var updated_name = titleObj.name;
    var updated_phone = titleObj.phone;
    var updated_email = titleObj.email;
    });
});

 var panel = $('div#'+candidate_id+'.panel');
 panel.find('p#card_name').val(updated_name);                
 panel.find('div.card_details p#card_phone').val(updated_phone);               
 panel.find('div.card_details small#card_email').val(updated_email);

}
```

Why it is not throwing error when fetching the value but throws a error when updating the value ?

Comment: Where `candidate_id` is defined ?

Comment: Check the id of panel in console window of browser and try accessing it from there.

Comment: `[object HTMLInputElement]` is what you get when you have the reference to a DOM element, and try to put it into a string context. Your `candidate_id` is not a string, it refers the input element.